# If I recite this du'a 3 times are all my major and minor sins forgiven?

Tags: sin, dua, tawba

If I read Astagfiru-l-Laaha-l Azim allazi la ilaaha illa huw al-haiy al-Qaiyyum wa attubu ilayhi 3 times, are all my sins major sins and minor sins forgiven?
And shirk too because I have commited shirk before, and if not how to repent from all those sins.

Comment: Please avoid lengthy titles see in [our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/advice-for-writing-question-titles-on-islam-se)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to read any dua to ask for forgiveness, you just have to do a simple thing , you just have to repent and ask for forgiveness to allah in your own language and at that time you have to keep it in your mind that you will never do that sin again, allah will forgive your all sins even shirk,

Answer (score 0):

Which you read istighfar is enough to make tawba inshaAlloh. You should regret for your sins and do not repeat sins. Saying dua or istighfar with tongue is not enough, they should be said by heart. If you said istighfar with heart, you did tawba